# Calling garbage collector after read/write a file

Tags: .net-core

I'm facing an issue which is resolved by forcing the garbage collector.

My code is composed of one main function and two sub functions which write/read a file.
The problem is that when i don't call GC.Collect(), i've got an exception telling me that the "file is used by another process" when the write or the second read happend. 
I've tried to use stream Writer/Reader into a using, forcing to close the stream, forcing the dispose etc... but the only way i found to make it work without issue is to call de garbage collector.
I saw many post on stackOverflow which says that it's a bad practice to call carbage collector, and that the issue is probably due to bad code.
So could you please tell what's wrong ?

Main function : (//Do some stuff means that there is hiden code):

```
    public async Task myfunction ()
    {
        await ReadFileAsync(pathFileNumberOne);
        //DO SOME STUFF 
        await SerializeCalendar(Calendar, pathFileNumberOne);
        //DO SOME STUFF 
        await ReadFileAsync(pathFileNumberOne);                     
    }
```

The reading function :

```
    private async Task<string> ReadFileAsync(string path)
    {
        string strText = null;
        int nb_try = 0;

        while (strText == null && nb_try < 20)
        {
            try
            {
                strText = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(path);
                // Open the text file using a stream reader.
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e.Message);
                GC.Collect();
            }
            if (strText == null)
            {
                await Task.Delay(10);
            }
            nb_try++;
        }
        GC.Collect();
        return strText;
    }
```

And the writing function :

```
    private async Task SerializeCalendar(Ical.Net.Calendar calendar, string path)
    {
        var serializer = new CalendarSerializer();
        var serializedCalendar = serializer.SerializeToString(calendar);
        bool success = false;
        int nb_try = 0;
        while (success == false && nb_try < 20)
        {
            try
            {
                await File.WriteAllTextAsync(path, serializedCalendar);
                /*using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(path))
                {
                    await outputFile.WriteAsync(serializedCalendar);
                }*/
                success = true;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                success = false;
                _logger.LogError(e.Message);
                GC.Collect();
                await Task.Delay(10);
            }
            nb_try++;
        }
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Comment: It has two basic side-effects.  One is hiding a bug, forgetting to close the file.  The other is taking time, providing enough of a delay for something else trying to access the file as well to not cause a problem.  Temporarily disable the installed anti-malware product and try again without GC.Collect().

Comment: It doesn't work without GC.Collect, when if i disable the anti-malware product